# Injecting method interceptors in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I've searched all over the web for it and everyone (including) google suggests using `requestInjection()` but I still don't understand how to use it. I have a class that implements Method Interceptor:

```
public class CacheInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    private ILocalStore localStore;
    private IRemoteStore remoteStore;
    private CacheUtils cacheUtils;

    public CacheInterceptor() {
    }
   @Inject
    public CacheInterceptor(ILocalStore localStore, CacheUtils cacheUtils, IRemoteStore remoteStore) {
    this.localStore = localStore;
    this.cacheUtils = cacheUtils;
    this.remoteStore = remoteStore;
    }
}
```

And I have 3 classes that extends `AbstractModule`.

```
public class CacheUtilModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(CacheUtils.class);
    }
}

public class LocalCachingModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(ILocalStore.class).to(LocalStore.class);
    }
}

public class RedisCachingModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(IRemoteStore.class).to(RemoteStore.class);
    }
}
```

And I did the following for binding the interceptor

```
public class RequestScopedCachingModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        install(new CacheUtilModule());
        install(new LocalCachingModule());
        install(new RedisCachingModule());
        MethodInterceptor interceptor = new CacheInterceptor();
        requestInjection(interceptor);
        bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(),   Matchers.annotatedWith(Cacheable.class),
            interceptor);
    }

}
```

So basically, I want to inject the localStore, remoteStore, and cacheUtils in my MethodInterceptor with my own implementation mapped out in my 3 modules. But this didn't work. I guess I am just confused with requestInjection(). In the documentation, requestInjection does this

> Upon successful creation, the Injector will inject instance fields and methods of the given object.

But where do we specify the mapping between the interface and the implementation class? How can I get what I wanted to do to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`requestInjection`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestInjection-java.lang.Object-) will only inject fields and methods - it won't invoke the constructor and doesn't know anything about the `@Inject` annotations on your constructor. If you add `@Inject` to all of your fields your code should work as you expect.

Comment: So will it work with setters?  Just checked it and it works for setters! Thank you @condit